# DomainService Delete method not working. Why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, relational-database

My problem is this:

```
        Inspections
            InspectionItems
```

In my relational database I need to 'cascade' deletes so that there is no redundant data laying around. Eg If I delete an inspection it also needs to remove all the related items.

I have written the code into the Domain Service Class:

```
        public void IDInspectionDelete(string id)
        {
            var inspections = from a in ObjectContext.Inspections
                              where a.ID == new Guid(id)
                              select a;
            foreach (Inspection inspection in inspections)
            {
                var items = from a in ObjectContext.InspectionItems
                            where a.InspectionID == inspection.ID
                            select a;
                foreach (InspectionItem item in items)
                {
                    DeleteInspectionItem(item);
                }
                DeleteInspection(inspection);
            }
        }
```

Then in my view-model I call the function:

```
        context.IDInspectionDelete(id_string);
```

... Which does nothing. At all. Not a peep. The code will step through, no errors etc. but no deleting. I'm going to re-write it into my view-model and call

```
context.Remove(item)
```

which should work. But I would like it in the DomainService Class.

Unless, of course, this is a big no-no. Please explain why, if so.

Thank you!

Comment: I cannot see any commit or submit changes on context.

Comment: I would have your viewmodel remove the parent inspection record as it normally would. In your domain service, customize the behavior to include the cascading deletes of child records. Have your cake and eat it, too.

Comment: @SteveB ah yes, sorry - i also called context.SubmitChanges();

Comment: @AnthonyPegram that will be my last resort option - i don't like to change the basic DomainService CRUD methods as I constantly update the database structure which means the DomainService needs to be reloaded. I generally forget to copy the code. :/

Comment: Well, I would generally go a step farther than even I suggested, which would be have the domain service pass the call through to some other class (repository or BLL) that would express the logic. The domain service would be largely ignorant. But if you have your code structured differently and your database is in a constant state of flux, then that's a problem to sort through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution** to this question is to do it all in the Domain Service Class using the ObjectContext as so;

**DOMAIN SERVICE CLASS**

```
[Invoke]
public bool DeleteInspection(Guid ID)
{
    bool bResult = false;

    // get the inspection to delete
    Inspection inspection = this.ObjectContext.Inspections.Where(a=>a.ID == ID).FirstOrDefualt();

    // first delete all attached entities
    foreach (InspectionItem item in inspection.Items)
    {
        this.ObjectContext.DeleteObject(item);
    }

    // save changes
    this.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave);

    // then delete item itself
    this.ObjectContext.DeleteObject(inspection);

    // set result to true only if at least one record has been effected
    if (this.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave) >0)
        bResult = true;

    return bResult;        
}
```

**VIEW MODEL**

```
context.DeleteInspection(InspectionID, io =>
{
    if (io.Value)
        MessageBox.Show("Inspection successfully deleted");
}, null);
```

Answer (score -1):

**One option** is to use SQL triggering to the database table so that the cascade delete has nothing to do with the application at all. This means I can call `context.Remove(item)` and the database will cascade through the deletes.

Just in case it is useful to people, I'll put my SQL as well:

**SQL**

```
   ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[InspectionDeleteTrigger] 
   ON  [dbo].[Inspection] 
   INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Delete ALL Items Linked to deleted Inspection --
    DELETE FROM InspectionItem
    FROM InspectionItem AS tbl JOIN deleted AS d ON tbl.InspectionID = d.ID

    -- Delete current Inspection --   
    DELETE FROM Inspection  
    FROM Inspection AS tbl JOIN deleted AS d ON tbl.ID = d.ID

END
```